# Calculating multiple percentages from a column and creating a loop based on that in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, percentage, calculation

I have a masterfile which stores employee data, and they can receive bonus each month based on their salary between (x% to y%).

```
import pandas as pd
masterfile = {'Name': ['Joe', 'Jack', 'William', 'Avarel'], 'Base Salary': [100, 80, 60, 40],'Min Bonus': [80, 80, 70, 60],'Max Bonus': [120, 120, 110, 100],'Local Currency': ['EURO', 'EURO', '$', '$']}
df = pd.DataFrame(masterfile)
print(masterfile)

df["Base Salary"]=df["Base Salary"].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)

Name=df["Name"].values
Base=df["Base Salary"].values
localc=df["Local Currency"].values

zipped = zip(Name,Base,localc)

for a,b,c in zipped: 
    
    doc=DocxTemplate(file)
    
    context = {"Name":a,"Base":b,"localc":c}
    
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save('{}.docx'.format(a))
```

With this code I can export it to different .docx files but only the base salary. What I am trying to do is to calculate each bonus percentage between min and max bonus(i.e. for Joe : 80%,81%,82%etc until 120%) and create a different column for each percentage.

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from sample data?

Comment: expected output should be for Joe for example ( Joe, 100, 80, 81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120). I need to see each bonus percentage as a calculation between min and max bonus columns

Comment: in tuples? in columns? I ask for expected ouput because no idea about format of new column(s) ?

Comment: i need columns named as the relative percentage like in above example, 80%,81%,82% etc.